# Windows 10 and Ubuntu do not dual boot (after multiple attempts to fix)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

The title is quite self explanatory. I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now. To start off, I have a laptop with Win10 and a SSD+HDD system. The SSD is 250GB so I have space to play around with it. Currently Win10 is installed in the SSD and the HDD is mainly used as extra memory.

Firstly, I did a fresh windows 10 install. This was due to the fact that my BIOS was set to Legacy, and when I wanted to install Ubuntu I got "the force UEFI installation message". So I decided to disable Legacy mode and reinstall Win 10 in UEFI. After that, I have followed multiple guides to install Ubuntu.

At first, I tried the first option in installation to install automatically along Win10. After the install finished, the laptop booted automatically into Win10. No boot manager, no grub, no nothing.

I assumed that the install messed up something so

I tried again using the something else method. I mostly used [this guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/05/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10.html). Still didn't work. When I turn on the laptop it just boots automatically into Win10.

When I went in the BIOS to check the boot order I have first: USB, HDD, OS Boot manager, Network. These are my only options, no Ubuntu. I have also tried to move some of these up and down and see the results, no change.

[Boot-repair info summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24535507/)

Comment: I installed Easy UEFI and [this](http://i.imgur.com/9zQsWiy.jpg) is what I see. No GrubEFI boot.

Comment: Add manual entry from disk 1 GPT FAT  with the file I have outlined above. You will probably have to (Disable Fastboot) (Google that) as well, and move that entry to the top of the list.

Comment: Hmm... I don't really understand exactly what I have to do. This is my first time I am trying to do this, so it is all very new. Oh well, I guess I will have to stick to windows then. Thank you very much for the help you offered.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Here's a quick Video showing EasyUEFI. This is what worked for me. https://youtu.be/23712F5vC-k

Comment: EODCraft, thank you so much for making that video. I have done exactly what you showed me and it still did not work. Perhaps I did something wrong, but I don't think so.

I have also ran the boot repair utility. Here is the link to the summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24535507/

Answer (score 0):

You might have to, in UEFI menu, go to boot options, and then click on boot order. You will have to add shimx64.efi to your uefi boot order.

Answer (score 0):

Change the boot order in your motherboard settings. Alternatively locate the boot menu key could be delete, F5, F6, F7, F8, etc..

Try to see if uefi is an option and if it's enabled.

When you find it you should be able to use the arrow keys to go up and down the list simply select Ubuntu and hit enter.

It sounds like a grub issue you can attempt to fix it. There are a bunch of ways to do this however if you're not familiar with Linux than I suggest you use the live cd/USB etc..

If you use the live installer you can boot into the os and reinstall grub in the right location which should fix your issue. There are a ton of posts in these forums which can help you with that.

I've seen people unintentionally install grub on their installation media and not be able to boot into the os with out said media connected.

Be it cd USB w/e

One method you can use is plop. Plop is a nifty boot manager. If you go into your windows install you can check that out here

https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html

Plop has come along way and can now be installed within the os; been like that for years actually. Once you do that if you choose this method..  Reboot and plop will recognize your ubuntu install.

I didn't look at the links you posted. Sorry if I ask something covered there. Did you install Ubuntu with separate partitions?

Root home swap etc? If so you may have neglected to set the boot in which case nothing I've said nor anyone else's answer would help.

If you installed it on one part ion where did you install on the mbr?

If the boot loader is before windows, windows will nuke it and it won't work. If you reinstall windows it will again nuke the mbr and you won't be able to boot to a Linux install.